# Cassandra: how to setup client-to-node encryption?

Tags: java, ssl, cassandra

I've set up Cassandra client-to-node encryption using DataStax [guide](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureSSLClientToNode_t.html)

Client_encription_options from cassandra.yaml file:

```
 client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    keystore: /opt/key/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    cipher_suites:[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

The client using the default Java System properties for SSL:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/app/conf/.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=cassandra
```

But after connecting got error in Cassandra log:

```
INFO [Native-Transport-Requests:12] 2015-02-11 11:45:52,456 Message.java (line 397) Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xfb3df0e3, /192.168.43.13:32885 => /192.168.43.10:9042]
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 01000001000000160001000b43514c5f56455253494f4e0005332e302e30
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:871)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Cassandra 2.0.10.71, Java 1.7.0_75 with Java Cryptography Extension libs

Comment: have you verified that you're sending encrypted data? This error basically says that the packet is not encrypted using SSL (v2 or v3) or TLS protocol.

Comment: Can you set up cqlsh as client and see if you can make it work. I lean towards that you have issues on your client side rather than on the server side. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureCqlshSSL_t.html

Answer (score 3):

This is an INFO messages that suggest that a no ssl package has been set to your Cassandra node.  It seems that there is something trying to connect to your Cassandra node.

Have a look to the source code of the Netty java file which raise the exception. 
    org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:871)

```
  if (nonSslRecord) {
       // Not an SSL/TLS packet
        NotSslRecordException e = new NotSslRecordException(
        "not an SSL/TLS record: " + ByteBufUtil.hexDump(in));
        in.skipBytes(in.readableBytes());
            ctx.fireExceptionCaught(e);
            setHandshakeFailure(ctx, e);
   }

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.netty/netty-handler/4.0.30.Final/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#SslHandler
```

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-301